# How to resize output images in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, spyder, imshow

Hi i run this blurdetection code in python ( source : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/ )

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import cv2

def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in paths.list_images("images/"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and compute the
    # focus measure of the image using the Variance of Laplacian
    # method
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray)
    text = "Not Blurry"

    # if the focus measure is less than the supplied threshold,
    # then the image should be considered "blurry"
    if fm < 100:
        text = "Blurry"

        # show the image
    cv2.putText(image, "{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm), (10, 30),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    print("{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm))
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

with this 2173 x 3161 input file 
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3KSp.jpg)

and this is the output show
[the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBfeA.jpg)
The image is zoom in and dont shown full.

In the source code, they use 450 x 600 px input image :
[input in source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLXUM.png)
and this is the output :
[output in source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ltQF.png)

I think the pixels of the image influences of the output. So, how can i get the output like the output in source code to all image? 
do i have to resize the input image? How to? but if I do it I'm afraid it will affect the result of his blur

Comment: have you tried `cv2.resize()`? You can use it to just display how the output image looks like. `cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)`

Comment: Why not just create a `namedWindow` with flag `WINDOW_NORMAL`? ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html)) Then you get a resizable window that scales the image to fit it. Add `WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` for the scaling to retain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: How implement that?

Comment: What @DanMa meant was to use `cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` before `cv2.imshow("Image", image)`. Using this you will be able to resize the output window as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html).

> There is a special case where you can already create a window and load image to it later. In that case, you can specify whether window is resizable or not. It is done with the function cv2.namedWindow(). By default, the flag is **cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**. But if you specify flag to be **cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL**, you can resize window. It will be helpful when image is too large in dimension and adding track bar to windows.

I just used the code placed in the question but added line `cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` as mentioned in the comments.

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import cv2

def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    return cv2.Laplacian(image, cv2.CV_64F).var()

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in paths.list_images("images/"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and compute the
    # focus measure of the image using the Variance of Laplacian
    # method
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray)
    text = "Not Blurry"

    # if the focus measure is less than the supplied threshold,
    # then the image should be considered "blurry"
    if fm < 100:
        text = "Blurry"

        # show the image
    cv2.putText(image, "{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm), (10, 30),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)       #---- Added THIS line
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    print("{}: {:.2f}".format(text, fm))
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the exact same resolution as the example you've given, you can just use the `cv2.resize()` https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize method or (in case you want to keep the ratio of the x/y coordinates) use the imutils class provided in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/02/just-open-sourced-personal-imutils-package-series-opencv-convenience-functions/

You still have to decide if you want to do the resizing first. It shouldn't matter in which order you greyscale or resize.

Command you can add:
`resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (450, 600))`